# In SQL does a Primary Key in a create table enforce uniqueness?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint, composite-primary-key

Im wondering if on a relational table I set the two values below as a PRIMARY KEY if that automatically makes the table know that all entries should be unique....

```
CREATE TABLE UserHasSecurity
(
    userID int REFERENCES Users(userID) NOT NULL,
    securityID int REFERENCES Security(securityID) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(userID,securityID)
)
```

or do I need to be more explicit like this...

```
CREATE TABLE UserHasSecurity
(
    userID int REFERENCES Users(userID) NOT NULL,
    securityID int REFERENCES Security(securityID) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(userID,securityID),
     UNIQUE(userID,securityID)
)
```

Comment: When you use PrimaryKey you don't need the Unique keyword. The Unique keyWord is for other candidate keys: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key

Comment: Primary key will ensure uniqueness and not allow nulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need UNIQUE here. PRIMARY KEY will make sure there is no duplicate (userID,securityID) pairs.

Answer (score 1):

A `PRIMARY KEY` has to be unique, so you only need to declare as a primary key. The underlying index is unique by definition.

[Creating Unique Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175132%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to specify `UNIQUE` in addition to `PRIMARY KEY`. A primary key by definition must be unique.